# how can i write a program for checkbox clicked automatically with the help of database and displayed in bootstrap modal page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

hai iam trying to write a program for checkbox clicked automatically with the help of database....i am writing the code like this i.e., i am writing jsp project when i am clicked the user page it display the users details in the table format. in that it has two icons one is update and another one is delete...
when i am clicked on update its open a bootstrap modal page and display the user details in that i am using a checkbox tag..when the user is active its checkbox clicked automatically...but iam getting unclicked how can in resolve this...

`````
<div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-hover table-centered m-0">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Rolename</th>
                                                <th>Status</th>
                                                <th>Created On</th>
                                                <th>Modified On</th>
                                                <th>Status1</th>
                                                <th colspan="2">Options</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <% 
        int status=0; 
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        //Statement st = con.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
        pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from  m_Roles "); //sql select query
     ResultSet rs1=pstmt.executeQuery(); //execute query and set in ResultSet object "rs"
%>
        <tbody>
            <%
                while(rs1.next())
               {
                   status=rs1.getInt("IsActive");
            %>           
            <tr id="<%=rs1.getString("RoleID")%>">

                <th><%=rs1.getString("RoleName")%></th>
                <th><%=status%></th>
                <td><%=rs1.getString("CreatedOn")%></td>
                <td><%=rs1.getString("ModifiedOn")%></td>

               <!-- <td><input type="checkbox" id="" disabled="" name="active" parsley-trigger="change" <% if(status==1) { %> checked="checked" <% } %> ></td>-->
                <td><input type="text" id="" disabled="" name="active"<% if(status==1) { %> value="Active" <% }else{%>value="Inactive"<%} %> > </td>

                <td align="">
                           <!-- Update Icon -->
                        <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal">
                            <i class="mdi mdi-account-edit update" data-toggle="tooltip" 
                            data-rid="<%=rs1.getString("RoleID")%>"
                                                        data-rname="<%=rs1.getString("RoleName")%>"
                                                        data-check="<%=status%>"
                            title="Edit"></i>
                        </a> 
                </td>
                     <!-- Delete Icon Table -->
                    <td>
                           <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-rid="<%=rs1.getString("RoleID")%>" data-toggle="modal">
                               <i class="mdi mdi-delete delete" data-toggle="tooltip" 
                         title="Delete"></i></a>

                        </div>
                    </a>
                </td>



        <div id="editEmployeeModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" >
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title mt-0">Edit Roles</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                             <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="update_form">
                                    <div class="row">

                                                            <input type="hidden" id="rid_u" name="id" parsley-trigger="change" autocomplete="off" required placeholder="Enter First Name" class="form-control" id="firstName">


                                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Role Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                                            <input type="text" id="rname_u" name="rname" parsley-trigger="change" autocomplete="off" required placeholder="Enter First Name" class="form-control" id="firstName">
                                                        </div>
                                                        </div>


                                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                                            <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Active<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                                                <input type="text" name="check_box" id="check_u"/>
                                                                @if(check_u==1)
                                                                {
                                                                <input type="checkbox" id="act_u" checked="checked"  name="active" parsley-trigger="change" >
                                                                 }
                                                                 else
                                                                 {
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" id="act_u" name="active" parsley-trigger="change" >
                                                                 }

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                     <div class="form-group text-right mb-0">
                                                        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="type">
                                                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="update">Update</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                </form>



````
this is ajax code

<script>
  $(document).on("click", ".delete", function() 
    { 
        var uid=$(this).attr("data-id");
                $('#id_d').val(uid);
            });
            $(document).on('click','#delete',function(e) {
             var data = $("#delete_form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
                        data:data,
            url: "deleterole.jsp",
            //data:"uid="+id,
            method: "POST",//HTTP method.
            success: function()
                        {
                             //alert('Data deleted successfully !'); 
                            location.reload();
                             //setInterval('location.reload()',2000); 
            }
        });
    });
$(document).on('click','.update',function(e) {
        var id=$(this).attr("data-rid");
        var rname=$(this).attr("data-rname");
                var check_box=$(this).attr("data-check");
                $('#rid_u').val(id);
        $('#rname_u').val(rname);
                $('#check_u').val(check_box);

    });

    $(document).on('click','#update',function(e) {
        var data = $("#update_form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "post",
            url: "updaterole.jsp",
            success: function()
                        {
                            alert('Data updated successfully !'); 
                            location.reload();                      
            }
        });
    });
</script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $("#act_u").change(function()
                {
                    // var t=document.getElementById('check_u').value;
              //if("#check_u").
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true)
                    {
                        $("#check_u").val("1");
                    }

                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false)
                    {
                        $("#check_u").val("0");
                    }
        });
    });
    </script>
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly put your `@if(check_u==1) {..` inside your jquery code and only leave `<input type="checkbox" id="act_u" name="active" parsley-trigger="change">` in modal. Also ,your jquery code will look like below :

```
$(document).on('click', '.update', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-rid");
  var rname = $(this).attr("data-rname");
  var check_box = $(this).attr("data-check");
  $('#rid_u').val(id);
  $('#rname_u').val(rname);
  $('#check_u').val(check_box); 
  //checking value of checkbox
  if (check_box == 1) {
    //checked
    $('#act_u').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    //unchecked
    $('#act_u').prop('checked', false);
  }

});
```